# Battery Usage in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: battery

The problem is:
In the evening, when I shut down my laptop, it is 100% battery charged.
But when I switch it on next morning, the battery indicator is down to 80% or something. If I switch it on after two days, the indicator is around 76%.
My Laptop is HP 249TU (64 bit).

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Its Battery/system  Problem, not OS, as OS does not remain alive in shut down state.

Comment: This is not about Ubuntu

Comment: But it was happening on my previous Laptop also. The same problem on two different systems cannot be common.

Comment: How do you switch off the laptop?

Comment: Click on the corner button, click the Switch off button, Thats it. The Laptop shuts down and the black screen comes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a NiMH battery. All batteries self-discharge when they are not used. Li-Ion batteries do this only a little (few percent per month), but according to [Wikipedia NiMH batteries article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel%E2%80%93metal_hydride_battery#Self-discharge):

> The self-discharge is 5–20% on the first day and stabilizes around 0.5–4% per day at room temperature

NiMH batteries do have the advantage of having a bigger capacity than Li-Ion though.

If you are in doubt whether your system was actually shutdown and didn't go into sleep mode, check your system logs, for example with:

`grep -i 'shutdown\|sleeping\|hibernat\|resumed' /var/log/syslog*`