# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS : the battery-indicator for wireless mouse is not working

Tags: mouse, battery

The battery indicator is not working for my Logitech Mouse which is wireless. I have tried to change the BIOS and it did not work, also tried to do the suggestions posted in the other sites and still it does not work. I have changed the battery (in the wireless mouse) from an old one to a new one and it is still stuck at 70%. I use Cinnamon desktop, installed recently.

I see only suggestions for laptop batteries ([Battery Usage in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/809505/battery-usage-in-ubuntu-16-04)), but this is a desktop machine. Please let me know how to re-install the whole Cinnamon desktop again if that needs to be done.

[image]

Comment: sudo apt-get remove indicator-power && sudo apt-get install indicator-power Sudo apt-get update Good luck with that.

Comment: Please see [here](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) for help on formatting your posts. That said, what do you mean it's not working? The image you show would suggest it is working fine. Also, when you write things like " also tried to do the suggestions posted in the other sites" please tell us exactly what you tried. Otherwise we might just give you the same solutions.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, like i explained earlier its stuck at 70%.